# No such entity cartId when send POST on /rest/default/V1/carts/mine/payment-information

Tags: magento2, rest-api, magento2.4, stripe

According to documentation - **https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/rest/tutorials/orders/order-create-order.html**

I'm trying to make call on **/rest/default/V1/carts/mine/payment-information** with body:

```
{
  "paymentMethod": {
      "method": "stripe_payments"
  },
  "billing_address": {
    "email": "jdoe@example.com",
    "region": "New York",
    "region_id": 43,
    "region_code": "NY",
    "country_id": "US",
    "street": [
      "123 Oak Ave"
    ],
    "postcode": "10577",
    "city": "Purchase",
    "telephone": "512-555-1111",
    "firstname": "Jane",
    "lastname": "Doe"
  }
}
```

and getting error:

```
{
"message": "No such entity with %fieldName = %fieldValue",
    "parameters": {
        "fieldName": "cartId",
        "fieldValue": 0
    },
    "trace": "#0 /bitnami/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/QuoteRepository.php(232): Magento\\Framework\\Exception\\NoSuchEntityException::singleField('cartId', 0)\n#1 /bitnami/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/QuoteRepository.php(136): Magento\\Quote\\Model\\QuoteRepository->loadQuote('loadByIdWithout...', 'cartId', 0, Array)\n#2 /bitnami/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\\Quote\\Model\\QuoteRepository->get(0)\n#3 /bitnami/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\\Quote\\Model\\QuoteRepository\\Interceptor->___callParent('get', Array)\n#4 /bitnami/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\\Quote\\Model\\QuoteRepository\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}(0)\n#5 /bitnami/magento/htdocs/generated/code/Magento/Quote/Model/QuoteRepository/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\\Quote\\Model\\QuoteRepository\\Interceptor->___callPlugins('get', Array, Array)\n#6 /bitnami/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Service/PaymentFailuresService.php(102): Magento\\Quote\\Model\\QuoteRepository\\Interceptor->get(0)\n#7 /bitnami/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/module-checkout/Helper/Data.php(231): Magento\\Sales\\Model\\Service\\PaymentFailuresService->handle(0, 'Please check th...', 'onepage')\n#8 /bitnami/magento/htdocs/vendor/stripe/module-payments/Plugin/PaymentInformationManagement.php(68): Magento\\Checkout\\Helper\\Data->sendPaymentFailedEmail(Object(Magento\\Quote\\Model\\Quote\\Interceptor), 'Please check th...')\n#9 /bitnami/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): StripeIntegration\\Payments\\Plugin\\PaymentInformationManagement->aroundSavePaymentInformationAndPlaceOrder(Object(Magento\\Checkout\\Model\\PaymentInformationManagement\\Interceptor), Object(Closure), 6, Object(Magento\\Quote\\Model\\Quote\\Payment\\Interceptor), Object(Magento\\Quote\\Model\\Quote\\Address\\Interceptor))\n#10 /bitnami/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\\Checkout\\Model\\PaymentInformationManagement\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}(6, Object(Magento\\Quote\\Model\\Quote\\Payment\\Interceptor), Object(Magento\\Quote\\Model\\Quote\\Address\\Interceptor))\n#11 /bitnami/magento/htdocs/generated/code/Magento/Checkout/Model/PaymentInformationManagement/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\\Checkout\\Model\\PaymentInformationManagement\\Interceptor->___callPlugins('savePaymentInfo...', Array, NULL)\n#12 [internal function]: Magento\\Checkout\\Model\\PaymentInformationManagement\\Interceptor->savePaymentInformationAndPlaceOrder(6, Object(Magento\\Quote\\Model\\Quote\\Payment\\Interceptor), Object(Magento\\Quote\\Model\\Quote\\Address\\Interceptor))\n#13 /bitnami/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest/SynchronousRequestProcessor.php(95): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)\n#14 /bitnami/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest.php(188): Magento\\Webapi\\Controller\\Rest\\SynchronousRequestProcessor->process(Object(Magento\\Framework\\Webapi\\Rest\\Request\\Proxy))\n#15 /bitnami/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\\Webapi\\Controller\\Rest->dispatch(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#16 /bitnami/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\\Webapi\\Controller\\Rest\\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)\n#17 /bitnami/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\\Webapi\\Controller\\Rest\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#18 /bitnami/magento/htdocs/generated/code/Magento/Webapi/Controller/Rest/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\\Webapi\\Controller\\Rest\\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)\n#19 /bitnami/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(116): Magento\\Webapi\\Controller\\Rest\\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#20 /bitnami/magento/htdocs/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php(24): Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http->launch()\n#21 /bitnami/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(263): Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http\\Interceptor->launch()\n#22 /bitnami/magento/htdocs/index.php(39): Magento\\Framework\\App\\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http\\Interceptor))\n#23 {main}"
}
}
```

**I was trying to put "cartId" with id of shopping-card created by magento rest api, but result was the same.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, first of all, error occurs every time you have done something wrong, it doesn't matter it's invalid postcode, invalid region_id or something else. It's generic error, for example if you provide incorrect region_id for region this error will occur instead of for example "Your region_id is incorrect" or something like that.

In my case, the same error occurred when i incorrectly pass region_id or don't provide "additional_data" for stripe payments. This error doesn't tell you anything.

**First case:**
This is how request body should look for stripe payments:

```
{
  "paymentMethod": {
      "method": "stripe_payments",
      "additional_data": {
          "cc_save": false,
          "cc_stripejs_token": "pm_card_visa:visa:4242"
      }
  },
  "billing_address": {
    "email": "jdoe@example.com",
    "region": "New York",
    "region_id": 43,
    "region_code": "NY",
    "country_id": "US",
    "street": [
      "123 Oak Ave"
    ],
    "postcode": "10577",
    "city": "Purchase",
    "telephone": "512-555-1111",
    "firstname": "Jane",
    "lastname": "Doe"
  }
}
```

You have to add two additional parameters - **only for stripe payments with this plugin - https://marketplace.magento.com/stripe-stripe-payments.html**

**Second case:**
If your magento store works in USA everything is working correctly, but for other countries you have to configure it in admin panel:
**Go to** Store >> Configuration >> General >> Country Options

In each request you have to provide correct **region, region_id, region_code and country_id** parameters on each step of this tutorial: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/rest/tutorials/orders/order-prepare-checkout.html

The list of available region codes is in database, in your magento database you have to check codes and ids by SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM directory_country_region
```

and if you get prefix of your country like: "PL" or "US" you can check regions ids and codes by:

```
SELECT * FROM directory_country_region WHERE country_id = "PL";
```

that shows you:
[image]

and now i can use this informations in request (for małopolska in my case):

```
{
  "paymentMethod": {
      "method": "stripe_payments",
      "additional_data": {
          "cc_save": false,
          "cc_stripejs_token": "pm_card_visa:visa:4242"
      }
  },
  "billing_address": {
        "email": "XXX@XXX.com",
        "region": "małopolskie",
        "region_id": 801,
        "region_code": "PL-12",
        "country_id": "PL",
        "street": [
            "Street XX"
        ],
        "postcode": "XX-XXX",
        "city": "Kraków",
        "telephone": "XXX-XXX-XXX",
        "firstname": "Marcin",
        "lastname": "Warzybok"
  }
}
```